# neo4j not working on localhost

Tags: neo4j, localhost

Neo4J VERSION: 3.2.3

SYMPTOMS:
Neo4j is ready. Browse to http://0.0.0.0:7474/ I get 'This site can’t be reached'

Similarly using py2neo:
graph = Graph()
Traceback (most recent call last):

Unauthorized: http://localhost:7474/db/data/

I realize this is configuration error on some front but have have not been able to find a solution online. I can however access non-local neo4j databases, which is even more confusing.

Help appreciated, Will

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: using windows 7

Answer (score 3):

you should visit it with "http://localhost:7474" and neo4j will assert you to change the password when fist access.